# @Cacheable breaks DependencyInjection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, annotations, proxy-classes

I stumbled upon a case where the AOP proxy created by using @Cacheable breaks the dependency injection in Spring 3.1.1. Here is my scenario:

I have an interface and a class implementing this interface using @Cacheable at the implemented method.

Example interface:

```
public interface ImgService {
    public byte[] getImage(String name);
}
```

Example implementation:

```
public class ImgServiceImpl implements ImgService {

    @Cacheable(cacheName = "someCache")
    public byte[] getImage(String name){//TODO};

    protected String someOtherMethod(){//};
}
```

I also have to JUnit test classes - one which injects the interface and one the implementation:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:META-INF/spring.xml" })
public class ImgServiceTest {

    @Inject
    private ImgService;
}
```

and

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:META-INF/spring.xml" })
public class ImgServiceImplTest {

    @Inject
    private ImgServiceImpl;
}
```

Dependency injection for the interface works fine. However, when I get to injecting the implementation in the second test class I get an *"Injection of autowired dependencies failed"*. I was able to debug it and it appears that *ClassUtils.isAssignableValue()* wrongly compares the desired type to the proxy class. It is called by *DefaultListableBeanFactory*. What is even stranger is that if I remove the @Cacheable annotation from the implemented method and add it to some other protected/private method, dependency injection works fine again. Is this a bug and what would be the correct approach to handle this situation?

Comment: Here is one more good reference - http://blog.springsource.org/2012/05/23/understanding-proxy-usage-in-spring/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, so here is the solution I came up finally. I implemented a simple method that attempts to extract the target object from the proxy based on its implementation of the `org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised` class:

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked"})
public static <T> T getTargetObject(Object proxy, Class<T> targetClass) {
  if (AopUtils.isJdkDynamicProxy(proxy)) {
    try {
        return (T) ((Advised)proxy).getTargetSource().getTarget();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
  } else {
    return (T) proxy;
  }
}
```

My implementation test class now looks like this:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "classpath*:META-INF/spring.xml" })
public class ImgServiceImplTest {

    @Inject
    private ImgService imgService;

    private ImgServiceImpl imgServiceImpl;

    @PostConstruct
    public void setUp() {
        imgServiceImpl = getTargetObject(imgService, ImgServiceImpl.class);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 10):

It's not a bug, it's an expected side-effect of using JDK dynamic proxies for AOP implementation.

Since all calls to the cacheable method of `ImgServiceImpl` should go through the dynamic proxy of type `ImgService`, there is no way to inject this dependency into a field of type `ImgServiceImpl`.

When you move `@Cacheable` to `private` or `protected` method, injection works because `@Cacheable` doesn't take effect in this case - only `public` methods can be adviced using proxy-based AOP.

So, you should either declare fields to be injected as `ImgService`, or configure Spring to use target class-based proxies instead using `proxy-target-class = "true"`.

Yet another option is to configure Spring to use [AspectJ-based AOP implementation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-using-aspectj) (requires compile-time or load-time weaving).

It's applicable to all AOP-based features provided by Spring (transactions, security, async execution, cache, custom aspects, etc).

**See also:**

- [7.6 Proxying mechanisms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It still seems strange to me that the ClassUtils method doesn't handle this, as it seems to take not much more than an if statement.